# geometry margins and text width don't add up

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry

I'm making a set of cards with text elements read from a csv file and placed on each card.  I've simplified my layout problem in the example below.  (The full version has additional graphics, hence my use of tikz.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=3.74in,paperheight=2.24in,top=.45in, bottom=0.45in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\pagenumbering{gobble} % supress page numbering
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

% lay out elements on the card
% #1 text of the phrase
\newcommand{\card}[1]{
  \tikz {
      \node[text width=2.74in, text height=.89in, draw=black,align=center,font=\large\bf] at (0in, 0.88in) { #1  }; 
  }
}

\begin{document}
\card{I like coffee.}
\card{Fresh squeezed juice is the best...}
\card{Fish swim.}

\end{document}
```

With the paperwidth 3.74 and half inch margins, why does the textwidth of 2.74in overlap the right margin as seen below?

[image]

Comment: There's also `\marginparsep` to be taken into account

Comment: you need to set the option `inner sep=0pt` for your node. By the way `geometry` have a `showframe` option

Comment: thanks @touhami -- that worked for me.  I've added your suggestion as an answer

Comment: Isn't it easier to set `textwidth=2.74in` instead of setting the left and right margins?

Answer (score 2):

Answered in a comment.  This works:

```
      \node[inner sep=0pt, text width=2.74in, text height=.89in, draw=black,align=center,font=\large\bf] at (0in, 0.88in) { #1  };
```

[image]